# How to create Vector from vertices

Tags: openlayers

Is there any way to create a `Vector` object from a list of vertices? Basically what I'm trying to do is be able to draw a polygon on the map, save the vertices of that polygon in persistent storage and re-draw it later. I am able to save the `bounds` of the polygon and redraw the `Vector` using these, but then all I get is a box around the polygon. I'm open to other ideas besides storing a list of vertices as well, this just seemed like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the vector layer [features](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.features).

```
var features = yourVectorLayer.features;
```

You may then use GeoJSON to serialize the features using [write](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON.write).

To deserialize them use read.